# How to Turn Some Functions to an Independent Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget

I need to turn these two functions : _collectKeywords and _matchKeywords into a Widget, so I can reuse them another time. I have tried it, but I don't know how and where to instatiate the a widget that only processes data without returning any value. Can somebody help me?
//please don't mind the UI, button's color, etc

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttermatchcard/cardButton.dart';
class MainMenu extends StatelessWidget {

  void _accessCardMatcher(String butKeyword)
  {
    _collectKeywords(butKeyword);
  }

//================================================
  String _keyword_1;
  String _keyword_2;
  void _collectKeywords(String _keyword_now){

      if(_keyword_1==null)
      {
        _keyword_1=_keyword_now;
      }
      else{
        _keyword_2=_keyword_now;
        _matchKeyword(_keyword_1,_keyword_2);
      }
  }

  void _matchKeyword(_keyWord_one, _keyWord_two){
    if(_keyWord_one==_keyWord_two){
      //Lock the But
      print("MATCH!!!!");
    }
    _keyword_1=null;
    _keyword_1=null;
  }
//================================================

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      //textBaseline: ,
      children: <Widget>[

        Container(
        child: Text("Match Card", style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 50,
          color: Colors.amber,
          fontFamily: "FreeHand"

        ),
        ),
      ),
        Icon( Icons.filter_none,
          color: Colors.amber,
          size: 40,
        ),

        SizedBox(
          height: 30,
        ),

        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            //But Start
            CardButton(
              onTapExecute:_accessCardMatcher,
              keyword: "start",
              text: Text("STA", style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            ),
            //But Start2
            CardButton(
              onTapExecute:_accessCardMatcher,
              keyword: "start",
              text: Text("RT", style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            ),

            SizedBox(
                width: 10,
            ),

            //But Option
            CardButton(
              onTapExecute:_accessCardMatcher,

              keyword: "option",
              text: Text("OPT", style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            ),

            CardButton(
              onTapExecute:_accessCardMatcher,

              keyword: "option",
              text: Text("ION", style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            ),

          ],
        ),

        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),

        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

            //But
            CardButton(
              onTapExecute:_accessCardMatcher,

              keyword: "credit",
              text: Text("CRE", style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            ),
            CardButton(
              onTapExecute:_accessCardMatcher,

              keyword: "credit",
              text: Text("DIT", style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question and explanation are not understandable ! Can you please say what the result and flow you want ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Basically: I have a screen. The screen has two buttons. If those two buttons are clicked, then print "yey". Now, to check whether those two buttons have been clicked, I need a function to check the condition of those two buttons. Instead of copy-paste this function everytime I make a new screen, I think it'll be better if I turn it into a widget, then use this widget everytime I want to check if there are two buttons that have been pressed. The problem is, I don't know how to turn this function to a widget. … anyway, thanks for replying

Comment: So what I understood was you want to invoke a function/method if both buttons clicked in any order ! Is it ??? And you want those functions/methods to be used in many screens ?

Comment: correct! That's it

Answer (score 0):

Its a sample, Modify as your requirement !

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int buttonCount = 0;
  String textYouWantToModify = '';
  TextEditingController te;

  CommonMethods methods = CommonMethods();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    te = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title')),
        body: Container(
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
              //Other widgets like TextFiled to save text......or whatever
              TextField(
                controller: te,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Type something 1',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      buttonCount++;
                      if (buttonCount == 2) {
                        methods.method1(te.text);
                        methods.method2();
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  child:
                      Text('Button 1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
              RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      buttonCount++;
                      if (buttonCount == 2) {
                        methods.method1(te.text);
                        methods.method2();
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  child:
                      Text('Button 2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
              //Other widgets.....
            ]))));
  }
}

class CommonMethods {
  void method1(String s) {
    //your code.....
    print(s);
  }

  void method2() {
    //your code.....
  }
}
```